# No alarm fired with setRepeating when setting triggerAtMillis to System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: android, triggers, notifications, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I'm trying to fire a alarm every 5 minutes but my manager doesn't fire anything when setting the triggerAtMillis param to my current system time. Any idea how I can fix this?

```
  manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  int alarmType = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP;
  long intervalTime = 5*60*1000;
  manager.setRepeating(alarmType, System.currentTimeMillis(),intervalTime,pendingIntent);
```

This is my code when starting my alarm. So when I set the triggerAtmillis to triggerTime, it does fire but not exactly every 5 minutes.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context = null;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    context = arg0;
    System.out.println("test");
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("test")
                    .setContentText("test");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

My Receiver class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the alarm type

```
int alarmType = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP;
```

To

```
int alarmType = AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP;
```

According to api doc, `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` means

> time since boot, including sleep

while `RTC_WAKEUP` means

> wall clock time in UTC

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it :)